# How to change the default localhost ip in mysql on windows 10

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have installed a standalone Visual Basic application on my PC (Windows 10). In which the application is connecting a remote server (IP like `192.1xx.x.xxx`). 
When I run the application it's giving an error;

> User connection fail. Missing server/database. Unable to connect MySql hosts.

I have the VBScripts and MySQL databases which are used in the application. I don't know much about VB to build the application using the scripts. Can anybody guide me to rebuild it?

or

How can I change my MySQL default IP? and Will it solve my problem?

Here is some code:

```vb
Sub con()
    If System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern <> "dd/MM/yyyy" Then
        MsgBox("System Date Format is: " & System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern & vbCrLf & _
               " compartable on British Date Format only.." & vbCrLf & _
               "Change Short Date format to : dd/MM/yyyy" & vbCrLf & _
               "And Try Again")
        'System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        End
    End If
    Uid = "root"
    'PWord = "xxxxx"
    PWord = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    'PWord = "server2"
    datbase = "xxxxx"
    Myserver = ""
    'Myserver = "192.xxx.x.xxx"
    MyserverCRy = "xxxxxx"
    'ConString = "server=" & Myserver & ";database=" & datbase & ";Uid=" & Uid & ";Pwd=" & PWord & ";MinimumPoolSize=10;maximumpoolsize=150;"
    ConString = "server=" & Myserver & ";database=" & datbase & ";Uid=" & Uid & ";Pwd=" & PWord & ";Pooling=false;"

    Try
        DBcon.ConnectionString = ConString
        DBcon.Open()
        DBcomm.Connection = DBcon
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("User Connection Fail" & vbCrLf & "Missing Server/Database" & vbCrLf & "Errors occurred during connection" & vbCrLf & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connecting Error")
        'Application.Exit()
        End
    End Try
    Try
        DBcon1.ConnectionString = ConString
        DBcon1.Open()
        DBcomm1.Connection = DBcon1
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("User Connection Fail" & vbCrLf & "Missing Server/Database" & vbCrLf & "Errors occurred during connection" & vbCrLf & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connecting Error")
        End
    End Try
    Try
        DBcon2.ConnectionString = ConString
        DBcon2.Open()
        DBcomm2.Connection = DBcon2
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("User Connection Fail" & vbCrLf & "Missing Server/Database" & vbCrLf & "Errors occurred during connection" & vbCrLf & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connecting Error")
        End
    End Try
    Try
        dbcon_Insert.ConnectionString = ConString
        dbcon_Insert.Open()
        dbcomm_Insert.Connection = dbcon_Insert
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("User Connection Fail" & vbCrLf & "Missing Server/Database" & vbCrLf & "Errors occurred during connection" & vbCrLf & e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connecting Error")
        End
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. Show the relevant parts of the MySQL server configuration as well.

Comment: Can you expand on *"standalone Visual Basic application"*, what are we talking?, VB.Net, VB6 compiled executable, VBA in Office Application or VBScript? At the moment it's not clear what you are using and where VBScript fits in.

Comment: stand alone..i mean to say its an executable file. VB and .net is used. Here is some code..

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Myserver = ""
'[...]
ConString = "server=" & Myserver & ";database=" & datbase & ";Uid=" & Uid & ";Pwd=" & PWord & ";Pooling=false;"
```

You're getting that error because you define `Myserver` as an empty string. Replace the empty string with the correct hostname or IP address.